# How would you add a hyperlink to a BG img using CSS?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, background

**CSS**

```
header.site-header .wrap { 
    background: url(http://jadeluxurycondos.com/jadeluxurycondos-new/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/header-banner.jpg) right top no-repeat;
}
```

This is what I am working with. 
Any insight would be grateful.

Here is the [home.php](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11e3c573b0d5cb575908e3881d6dc92793be429d/) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all and thank you for the help.

I have found a solution.  I left the image on the BG, then added a widget to the top right of the page where the image (banner sits), then added a text box to the widget area and added this

```
<div class="topbanner" onclick="window.location='http://jadeluxurycondos.com/jadeluxurycondos-new/jade-signature/'" style=" height: 102px;left: 37.5%;position: absolute;top: 0; margin-top: 32px;width: 585px;cursor: pointer;"><div>
```

The image appears to be clickable.  Check [here](http://jadeluxurycondos.com/jadeluxurycondos-new/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simpler:

```
<div>
    <a href="#your-link" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://jadeluxurycondos.com/jadeluxurycondos-new/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/header-banner.jpg" width="740px" height="104px" alt="Some other title" title="Some title" />
    </a>
</div>
```

This creates a link that is an image.

***EDIT*** after more info came to light.

From what I've gathered so far... you're using the "[Open Floor Plan](http://openfloorplan.aethemes.com/)" Theme for Wordpress. (Maybe ask them for [support](http://www.agentevolution.com/contact-us/)? After all you paid for a theme.)

**The simple method and recommended:**

That theme appears to have a widget position at the top right. Why not use that to add your banner-link?

**The hard-way hacking not-recommended method:**

In wordpress you can edit the theme files (not recommended) by going to Appearance then Editor. This will open up the theme editor view and on the right side you'll see all the files of the currently active theme. You then could search those files for the HTML tag  and add the above modifications.

The file that could have what you're looking for could be the header.php or index.php, but if it isn't there just sift through the other files until you find it.

The html markup would look something like this:

```
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="wrap">
        It will contain more stuff in here...
    </div>
</header>
```

It will probably contain a lot more classes and PHP code...

---

**The Widget Method**

Add your banner code in a Text widget. You can add the CSS styling in-line, so that you won't have to upload anything else.

Add the CSS property for the parent container:

```
<style>header.site-header .wrap { position:relative; }
```

Then add the CSS for your element:

```
.mybanner { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; z-index:1; }
/* the widget with the social icons will probably need z-index aswell */
.CLASS-of-other-widget { position:relative; z-index:2; }
</style>
```

Now add your HTML code:

```
<div class="mybanner">
    <a href="#your-link" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://jadeluxurycondos.com/jadeluxurycondos-new/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/header-banner.jpg" width="740px" height="104px" alt="Some other title" title="Some title" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Please note that with the z-index, the other widget will cover the banner and the ability to click it. You could simply use another position for that widget and just have the banner there.

Comment: Would I add this into the css?

Comment: No, this goes in to the <body> of the page. You should also post on your question the HTML you are targeting with that CSS you have already posted.

Comment: The site is a wordpress site.  I am adding to the custom css.  I don't know where to add this if it must be the way u wrote your answer.

Comment: @MSiegle Next time, use correct tags. If you use any framework, tag it, please.

Comment: @Benio thank you for the correction.  1 for the memory bank.  cheers!

Comment: @Petsoukos I have asked for support and they suck....  I have tried to add to the top right widget, there are the social icons there and it doesn't look right.  Maybe if I give it a class in html?  Is this possible?  would u be willing to walk me thru this process?

Comment: The is from the home.php

Comment: You could add another widget, that will have a position:absolute; but the parent of that container should have position:relative; otherwise it will float off the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using CSS.

What you've done here is just passed the URL for the background.

If you want to add a link to the image, you can do this either by using a pair of anchor tags.

EG:

Add this in your HTML :

```
<a href='#'>
   <img src="...." />
</a>
```

OR by adding a click event on to the div.

EG:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('header.site-header .wrap').click(function(){
       window.location.href = "Link";
   });
});
```

Comment: This is a wordpress site and i was adding to the custom css.  I am unfamiliar as to where to add the 2 codes u posted.

Comment: Ok.  Please pardon any of my ignorance, but I am not sure how to add the code you posted.  Which php file am I supposed to add the Html to, as well as the JS?

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean. But for my sake, this was a pre-made theme.  I am just trying yo customize a banner in the header area and hyperlink it to another page on the site.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I have no idea where to add either code you posted.  There is no HTML file.  It's all PHP.  this is a wordpress theme.

Comment: That is what I have been saying.  I do not know where to add your code.

Comment: You need to share your code so that i can tell you where to keep it. I cannot assume which files are you using here.

Comment: Is this a live site? Could you provide us with a URL to the page you're trying to add this ?

Comment: In the top right is the banner - http://jadeluxurycondos.com/jadeluxurycondos-new

Comment: Well, since I don't know the structure of the Theme I cannot help... Did you try to contact the developer you bought it from? I've edit my answer to include some general tips for what you need...

Comment: I have contacted the developer, but hasn't help at all.  Is there a way I can get u the files so you can look at it?

Comment: i just want to add a hyperlinked banner in the header sitting behind the social media icons in wordpress.  I have beat my brains about it and cannot figure it out.